# R error: "New Column would leave holes after existing columns"

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, one is accuracy for a task and the other is response time (RT).  I'm trying to get only get the RT's for correct trials, rather than all trials.  I've made it so the incorrect trials in the accuracy table are displayed as NA, and when trying to make the corresponding cells NA in the RT table, I seem to be getting the error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, which(is.na(ACC)), value = NA) : new columns would leave holes after existing columns
```

The code is fairly simple - I've tried it with randomly generated data and it seems to work just fine.  The code is as follows:

## Open the files

```
ACC <- read_excel("PJ_ACC_TABLE.xlsx", sheet = 1)
RT <- read_excel("PJ_RT_TABLE.xlsx", sheet = 1)
```

## Change errors to NA

```
ACC <- ifelse(ACC>0,1,NA)
```

## Change

```
RT[which(is.na(ACC))] <- NA
```

My ACC table looks something like:

[ACC table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpCBv.png)

While my RT table looks something like:

[RT table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd2iK.png)

I noticed that after I change the ACC table to include the NA's, it turns into a vector.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please make a reproducible example as we do not have acess to your xlsx files. Also add what result you expect.

Comment: You don't need to work with two separate data frames, why not combine them and then try what you want to get?

Comment: I will try to add in the tables, but am having some trouble.  But the result I want is the RT table to have NA's in the same cells (e.g. Column A row 1) as the ACC table.

Also, I'm not sure how that would work Mon2us; I'm trying to get the RT's for only correct trials.  Even if the ACC cells were next to the RT cells, would i be able to make it so only correct RT's were averaged?

Comment: I edited my post to include pictures of my tables.  The desired result is to replace RT cells with the corresponding NA cells from the ACC table (thus only keeping the accurate RTs and replacing the errors with NA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index `RT` with `is.na(ACC)` like this. This answer will work if RT and ACC have the same dimension.

```
#example data
RT <-data.frame(matrix(1:25,ncol=5))
ACC <-data.frame(matrix(rep(1,25),ncol=5))
ACC[c(1,3,5),c(2,3,4)] <-NA

#Put NA in RT where ACC is NA
RT[is.na(ACC)] <-NA
RT

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1  1 NA NA NA 21
2  2  7 12 17 22
3  3 NA NA NA 23
4  4  9 14 19 24
5  5 NA NA NA 25
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  I have one question, that final command is very similar to the one I had in my original script, but removes the "which".  What does adding "which" add to the command?

Comment: `is.na` is a logical function which gives you TRUE or FALSE. It also keeps the dimension of the object whereas `which(is.na(ACC))` will give you a vector. In this case, you can't index a data.frame with a vector.